# how to compare two arrays that are in the same order using php

Tags: php, arrays

Am having the following two arrays:

```
    $array_1=array("a,b,c,d");
    $array_2=array("a,c,c,b");
```

how do i compare this two such that it will return the value `a` and `c` because they are the same in the same order

Comment: can you compare using for loop

Comment: yes you can use `for` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the array as follows and check for the same order for both array as follows:

```
  $array_1=array('a','b','c','d');
    $array_2=array('a','c','c','b');

$array_3 = array_intersect_assoc($array_1,$array_2);
echo implode(' , ',$array_3);

// or you can use the following method 

    for($i = 0;$i < count($array_1);$i++){
        if($array_1[$i] === $array_2[$i]){
            echo $array_1[$i].' , ';
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use use `array_intersect_assoc()`

Comment: its not displaying any result

Comment: <?php
 $array_1=array('a','b','c','d');
 $array_2=array('a','c','c','b');
 var_dump(array_intersect_assoc($array_1, $array_2));

Answer (score 0):

you can use array_intersect() method

```
array_intersect($array1, $array2);
```

You can learn about array intersect from this [Link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp)

Comment: Array intersect does not used to check for element order. It just show the common elements in both the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the array_diff_assoc function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
   $input_array1 = array( "a","b","c","d");
   $input_array2 = array("a","c","c","b");

   print_r(array_diff_assoc($input_array1, $input_array2));

?> 
</body>
</html>
```

and also your declaration is wrong

Comment: thus is wrong coz array_diff_assoc will only return the differences not the matches and am not looking for that

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic implementation of how to compare two arrays using `for` loop,

```
<?php
$a = array ('a','d','c','f');
$b = array ('a','b','c','d');
function arr_compare ($a, $b) {
  $c = array();
  for ($i=0; $i < count($a)-1; $i++) {
    if ($a[$i] == $b[$i]) {
      $c[] = $a[$i];
    }
  }
  return $c;
}

$c = arr_compare($a, $b);
var_dump ($c);
?>
```